# Microsoft Excel error in macro when trying to copy/paste to a specified range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, copy-paste

I have some code that I'm writing for the purpose of copying all cells with conditional formatting (which in my sheet will always be rows), and then pasting it back in the same place to remove the formulas.

I'm getting a x400 error code, when I tried On Error Resume Next to see what would happen, and with only two rows selected by the macro it pasted the same two rows for the entire paste range I had selected.

I tried changing the paste range to match another macro I have used that does work, but still to no avail. If anyone can help me figure this out it would be much appreciated.

The code for my macro is shown below.

```
Sub Cement()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim selRange As Range

    For Each cell In Range("L5:AJ370")
        If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> cell.Interior.Color Then
            If selRange Is Nothing Then
                Set selRange = cell
            Else
                Set selRange = Union(selRange, cell)
                selRange.Copy

            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not selRange Is Nothing Then selRange.Select
    Range("L5:AJ5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just remove the conditional formatting? `Range("L5:AJ370").FormatConditions.Delete`

Comment: The cells I conditionally format are formulas showing data containing formulas like this, 
`=IFERROR(INDEX($F$5:$F$29,MATCH(L$4,$E$5:$E$29,0),MATCH(IF(TODAY()=$J5,TODAY(),""),$F$4:$F$4,0)),IFERROR(INDEX($G$5:$G$29,MATCH(L$4,$E$5:$E$29,0),MATCH(IF(TODAY()-1=$J5,TODAY()-1,""),$G$4:$G$4,0)),""))` 
I'm pulling live data from other cells linked to a data source and placing it into a cell position in my sheet to use for historical data. I'm trying to copy and paste the cell value to remove the formula so my table data won't change. CFormatting identifies what formula cells keep the data.

Comment: Ah! I understood you wanted to get rid of the conditional formatting formula. To convert a cell from a formula to the result of that formula, you can use: `cell.Value = cell.Value2` instead of copy/pasting